# Como ler um ficheiro excel e fazer o mapeamento

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, datagridview

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer ler um ficheiro excel e depois fazer o mapeamento para uma datagridview.

Código que experimentei :

```
var fileName = @"C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\test.xlsx";
var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
  using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "PARAC1" });
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["PARAC1"].ToString() + "] ";
      var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
      var ds = new DataSet();
      adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: E já experimentaste preencher a gridview com esse dataset? : Grivew1.datasource= ds.Table[0];

Comment: @RenatoAfonso isso não resulta

Comment: "Isso não resulta". Muito explicito. Deu erro? Mostra onde colocaste a linha de código que sugeri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void preencherDataGridView()
    {

        var fileName = @"C:\Desenv\Pasta1.xlsx";
        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;

        var conexao = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM [Plan1$]";

        var cmm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conexao);
        var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        conexao.Open();

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dr = cmm.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);

        conexao.Close();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: Onde está escrito "Plan1$" meto o que no meu código ?

Comment: Coloque o nome da aba da planilha que contém os dados.
Se você não souber, abra a planilha no Excel e olhe o nome da aba no canto inferior esquerdo.