# Como criar uma método genérico para leitura de xlsx

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de criar um método que leia um arquivo xlsx com diferentes dados e salve de acordo com o objeto fornecido.
Tipo:
Public object Leitor (object objeto, arquivoxlsx)
{
//Implementação
}

Tenho uma aplicação onde preciso repetir a implementação do leitor a cada objeto novo que vai ser criado e isso não tá bacana, mas não sei como criar esse modelo.

Comment: Faça uma pesquisa no site, tem muitas perguntas sobre isso, por exemplo essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240210/como-ler-um-ficheiro-excel-e-fazer-o-mapeamento  isso não resolve?

Comment: Então, infelizmente não, mas identifiquei um problema que impede a criação do genérico, de todo jeito não tem jeito, mas obrigado.